# Android Bluetooth Crashes Application When Remote Device Closes Socket

Tags: android, sockets, crash, bluetooth

I have connected my Android application to a Windows desktop machine via Bluetooth. The application interacts with the machine. At the end of the interaction the application on the desktop closes the socket that was opened between the Android and the desktop application.

Right when socket.close() is called on the Windows machine my Android app pops open a dialog saying that the application has stopped unexpectedly and then it quits. I have a breakpoint on the line in the ConnectedThread (like in the BluetoothChat sample) where I read the InputStream on the Android and that is not hit. I also have a breakpoint in the catch statement for the try surrounding the place where I read the InputStream. That one also does not get hit. So I have no idea how I can catch this error. Is this a bug?

Can anyone give me a hand? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just use the standard connect method. I was using some of the stock code from a sample which was not entirely optimal for what I was doing anyway, so I rewrote the loop that accepted the data. And now the bug has gone away. I am not sure what caused it since the sample code seemed quite short and clean. But now it works perfectly.